# Facebook channelUrl set but connect still shows blank window in IE7

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-7, cross-domain, connect

I'm facing one odd Facebook connect issue, I've set up the FB.init method with correct params as mentioned in the FB developer docs - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Checked various places that mention, setting correct channelUrl will solve the issue, in my case i'm setting it correctly but still getting a blank(channel.html) popup only in case of IE7, is anyone else able to replicate this issue?

Any help in relation to this will be highly appreciated.

I've checked the protocol and all other standards related to setting this property but still no luck. Please help.

Comment: I read that you must use port 80 if you're domain is localhost.  I'm fighting a very similar issue, unfortunately.